# How does the final Processbuilder command look like?

Tags: java, shell, ksh, processbuilder

I am running a shell script(ksh with shebang at top of script) from my java program using ProcessBuilder:

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh","-c"," . " + /somepath/script.ksh + " " + argument);
proc = processBuilder.start();
```

Everything works fine using my java program. I wanted to run the command on the command line and figured the command being run from the java program  was:

```
/bin/sh -c . /somepath/script.ksh argument
```

However, that does not work on the command line and I receive this error:

```
/somepath/script.ksh: line 0: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

Looks like the "-c" flag is expecting the next item to be a command(which in my statement is the source operator "."), and after that it is expecting more arguments. So my script(/somepath/script.ksh) is being taken as argument instead of a command. Why does it work with processbuilder in the java program? Is it creating the command differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` option to `/bin/sh` would make `sh` interpret the argument as a command line.  So instead of saying:

```
/bin/sh -c . /somepath/script.ksh argument
```

you'd need to say:

```
/bin/sh -c ". /somepath/script.ksh argument"
```

Alternatively, you could say:

```
/bin/sh /somepath/script.ksh argument
```

Comment: Thanks! So is the processbuilder statement that I have created, equivalent to just running: . /somepath/script.ksh argument , on the command line? OR is processbuilder sending down quotation marks around the command and arguments? Wanted to make sure I understood what processbuilder is doing differently

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh","-c"," . " + /somepath/script.ksh + " " + argument);
```

To

```
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh","-c","./somepath/script.ksh", argument);
```

Give *all* the parts of the `String[]` as a separate `String`.

### Further Tips

Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for the link,  I will make my changes. My processbuilder command is running fine though.  I was trying to determine the exact equivalent command it was running so I could run it in putty.

Comment: I can leave this answer here or delete it as 'noise'.  I'll leave it to your call.  Which would you prefer?

Comment: The link was helpful, especially since it points out that the processbuilder commands are not constructed as they are on the command line.